# How Can I stop spotify when press f1 button

Tags: spotify

I don't have english very well I'm sorry for this.

Whatever I want to stop spotify when press button How Can I do ?

Thanks

Comment: Why the python tag?

Comment: I forgot to write the title "with Python"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with autohotkey. The link below has a script to use keyboard shortcuts to control spotify, and you can change the play/pause to be F1, and eliminate the rest if you don't like them.

in line 29, replace `#!Down::` with `F1::`.

https://gist.github.com/jcsteh/7ccbc6f7b1b7eb85c1c14ac5e0d65195